# Fastest way of finding duplicates in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe like this:

```
date             IP                 date_2            IP_2
2020-02-17       81.195.104.48      2020-02-24        219.85.238.142
2020-02-17       83.71.247.175      2020-02-24        187.134.23.124
2020-02-17       83.71.247.175      Nat               NaN
```

I am trying to get duplicates when comparing `IP` and `IP_2` values. `IP` has more rows than `IP_2` hence I am checking if `IP_2` exsist in `IP` like so:

`df['duplicates']=df['IP_2'].isin(df['IP'])`

Is there a faster way of getting only the duplicated `df` rather than adding new column that checks `.isin()` method? Desired output would be a new dataframe holding only the duplicated values.

Thank you for your suggestions.

Comment: Are IP and IP_2 *on the same row* related? If not why are they in the same row of a single dataframe instead of 2 independant dataframes? And what prevents you to build an independant Series sharing the dataframe index?

Comment: I actually have 2 dataframes holding 2 columns, `date` and `ip` but I thought having it in one would make it easier to find duplicates.

Comment: Merge IP and IP_2 and sort it then you can find the duplicates easily.

Comment: It makes sense for values in one row to represent one single record. BTW did you here of the [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/397459)? You are asking for complex operations on a single dataframe, when what you need seems to be a simple merge.

Comment: In your example, IP contains duplicate entries. Does your real *date-IP* dataframe contain duplicated IP?

Comment: Yes, the reason I do not want to merge them in to one column is that I want to know if the duplicates were found in both `IP` and `IP_2`, because there could be a case where there is duplicates in `IP` or `IP_2` columns separately but not a case wher there is a matching entry in both rows.

Answer (score 2):

Set comparison seems to me the fastest way:

```
set_common = set(df['IP']) & set(df['IP_2'])
```

P.S. Another way is to actually play with IP format (i.e. turn it into integer, then do some kind of comparison, but this apparently would make sense for a very big table).

Comment: So as I understand I take a set of `IP` and a set of `IP_2`. Then linking them with `&` sign. Or does `&` means get the duplicates?

Comment: It's a standard set logical conjunction (= intersection = operation "and"). So it looks for common elements in two sets. Python's set is exceptionally fast in looking for such intersections.
Did I understand your task correctly? I assume you don't actually look for "duplicates" (inside a single column), but just common elements between the columns.

Comment: Yes, I am trying to find matches in `IP` column and `IP_2`. I do not care if there are duplicates in `IP` or `IP_2`. Only matches interest me.